# How to connect SUSE in GUI?

Tags: opensuse

I have taken VM running Suse Operating system but can anyone let us know how to connect and use in GUI mode.

how to configure to use GUI mode in Suse

Answer (score 0):

On SuSE server you should enable X11 support in the sshd configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

restart the SSH service on the server:

```
user@myserver:~$ sudo rcsshd restart
```

and connect from the client with X11 forwarding enabled:

```
ssh -X user@myserver.mydomain.com
```

Then you will be able to launch GUI programs remotely:

```
user@myserver:~$ firefox &
user@myserver:~$ nautilus &
```